# Yii 1.x. Задать в $criteria выборку с исключением

Tags: yii, criteria

Есть две таблицы:**user** and **student**, которые связаны по полях соответственно **id-id_user**, связь один ко многим.
Пример
user
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

student
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выбрать всех user'ов, которые не являются student'ами.
Это те юзеры которых нет в таблице студентов и те у которых поле end_date не null. В нашем примере это студенты с id: 3, 4.

Вот как я это делал:

```
$criteria->alias = 'u';
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN student s ON s.id_user = u.id';
$criteria->addCondition('s.id is NULL or s.end_date is not NULL');
```

Но здесь не учтено то когда у одного студента end_date null и не null. Юзера с ид=2 выбирает как не студента, хотя он студент. Если студент хотябы раз встречается в таблице студент и имеет end_date = null, то он в условие не попадает.

Comment: По идее пользователь #3 не студент, не понятно почему #2 тоже не студент... можете делать NOT IN запрос в student по ID из user и после добавить доп. условия в таблице student

Comment: можете помочь с этим критерием? Я не могу понять как задать в NOT IN то что нужно исключить. $criteria->addNotInCondition('s.end_date is NULL',array()); это вариант где 1-й параметр - the column name (or a valid SQL expression). А второе значения которые нужно исключить - у меня они пустые, так как я решил задать их в первом параметре как sql. Но это не работает